# fixed sidebar until a div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        // whether that's below the form
        if (y >= top) {
            // if so, ad the fixed class
            $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            // otherwise remove it
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

It sets `fixed` on my sidebar when I scroll down after a specific point. I want that my sidebar stops being `fixed` after it reaches a point, which could be 200px from the bottom of the whole page. How can I do this?

Comment: http://andreafedi.net/thoughts/ if you scroll down you see the sidebar which goes on the footer. I'd like that the sidebar stopped before (not fixed anymore)

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add a few more checks and calculations in your event handler. Here's some revised code that should do what you want:

```
$(function() {
    var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var footTop = $('#background2').offset().top - parseFloat($('#background2').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var maxY = footTop - $('#sidebar').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function(evt) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > top) {
            if (y < maxY) {
                $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed').removeAttr('style');
            } else {
                $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (maxY - top) + 'px'
                });
            }
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

You can see it in effect [at this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/VtPcm/).

Comment: this actually works, thanks. But there is a little problem: the sidebar does not "reach" the footer, why? http://andreafedi.net/thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you are after, but you could always try the following:

http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/
(An event can be fired when you scroll to an element)

or

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/whenScrollBottom
(Fires event once scrolled near to the bottom, i.e., Twitter or Facebook loading more feed items when you scroll to the bottom of the page)