# Not sure how to add Javascript code to Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the code from here, the main solution by rossipedia:
[fixed sidebar until a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213849/fixed-sidebar-until-a-div?rq=1)

Here's my [Tumblr page](http://strawberries777.tumblr.com/) and the part of the code the script is influencing (main is replaced with content):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
...

<style type="text/css">
#sidebarwrap {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 16.2em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

 #sidebar {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 16em;
  height: 570px;
  position: absolute;
}

#sidebar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#footer {
  border-top: 4px solid {color:Footer Border};
  background: {color:Footer Background};
  color: {color:Background};
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

#content {
  margin-bottom: 4.5em;
  margin-left: 18.5em;
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 550px;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Body

```
<body>
<div id="contain">
    <div id="sidebarwrap">
    <div id="sidebar">
    ...Stuff...
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    ...Stuff...
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<div id="footer-container">
...Stuff...
</div>
</div>
```

I then included the the script right before the /body as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...Script...
</script>
```

I keep spell checking and making sure everything is in order, but it all just won't work. At least not for that JS. The other JS's I used work just fine... The script is supposed to make my side bar scroll with the user and then stop right before overlapping the footer. Yet, the script acts likes its not even there, the sidebar doesn't move a single inch...
Heck, I even tampered with the original on its Fiddle page to make it the same layout and ordering as my page, and it still worked just fine.

Am I missing something? Everyone keeps talking about JQuery, and I'm not entirely sure what that is or if I'm supposed to use it... If someone could help me see what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it! :'D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you do need to load jQuery on your page to use the code you added. jQuery is a JavaScript library; it provides the "$" function.

To load jQuery in your page, add this *before* your fixed sidebar code:

```
<!-- Note that we have a closing tag right after the opening tag here. -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // Your code here
</script>
```

Comment: Oooh! I knew I was suspicious of those $ for a reason! I kept wondering why that was the only Javascript with them...
Thank you sooo much, I'll add it right now! :D

Comment: Hmm... It's still not working... I added it before as you said, enwrapping what I original had. Then I put it inside the code. After that didn't work either, I erased the first script tag and just left the one you gave me. I must be still doing something wrong. > ~ <

Comment: You'll need two separate sets of script tags -- first the jQuery script, then your code inside its own tags. I've edited my answer to demonstrate what it should look like.

Comment: Taking a look at your page, the error that was occurring because jQuery wasn't loaded is gone, so that's one problem solved. It looks like the script itself isn't working, though; let me see if I can spot the error.

Comment: Happy to help! Are you sure you have the scripts entered properly? The version of the site that's online still has the second set of script tags wrapped inside of the first. I was able to get it working while playing with the page dynamically in my browser, so you probably just need to straighten out your tags.

Comment: Wow, that's odd! It works now! I guess the preview for the script doesn't work, but when I actually apply it and go to the real page, it does. Oh man, always some little thing messing everything else up and leaving me frustrated for hours. X'D Again, thank you so much for your help! My page is finally complete! For now... >.>

Comment: For context, the Tumblr theme preview is really fickle about content sources, everything should be served via `https`.